# Insert new Mongo doc only if new using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using Morphia.

My doc is a POJO:

```
Hotel{
    @Id
    private long hotelID;
    private String anotherField1;
    private String anotherField2;
    private String anotherField3    
}
```

What is the proper way to insert a hotel in MongoDB **but only if it is a new `hotelID`?**

I am aware of the `update` method with the "`createIfMissing`" parameter in Morphia (https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Updating). But my operation is not an update, but a simple save (yes/no depending on the existence of the POJO in the db).

Any advice on the best way to proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a [save](http://morphiaorg.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#save-T-) operation:

> datastore.save(newObject);

If a document with the same `_id` exists, the entire document t will be replaced. Otherwise, a new document will be created.

The same can also be achieved with `createIfMissing` option which is basically an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) operation (update the document document if exists, otherwise create it).

The difference between the two commands is that if a document already exists the `save` will replace an entire document while `upsert` will update only the specified parts. For your use case the `save` method is probably a better match.

Comment: Is there a way to not get overwriting behavior? I would like to have Morphia throw an exception if Im trying to create a new document with an already existing id.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `createIfMissing` to true will perform an insert if no entity with the specified ID exists. If it does exist, it will update the existing entity.